# How to save Python script console output to a file?

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I want to run a Python script and save its console output to a file, while still being able to see the output in the console. For example, a "Hello World" script as simple as `print('Hello World')` would show `Hello World` in the console and also save this output to a file.

I was previously using `pythonscript.py > console_output.txt` to shell redirect, I can't see anything in the console with this solution (and for some reason, it no longer saves anything to the specified file, no idea why). This is a solution using Linux shell redirection, but now I would like to write a separate python script to do it.

I don't think I need any special error logging stuff. I'm currently using `try: except` blocks and just printing the Exception and then using that to find the error.

Comment: Check out the unix `script`command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do you something like this:

```py
def custom_print(message_to_print, log_file='output.txt'):
    print(message_to_print)
    with open(log_file, 'a') as of:
        of.write(message_to_print + '\n')
```

This way you can use `custom_print` instead of `print` to be able to both see the result in the console and have the result appended to a log file.

Comment: Would there be any way to incorporate pprint into this solution?

Comment: For anyone else that looks at this, I added a newline character so that last line of this function look like this > `of.write('\n' + message_to_print)`. Otherwise, all the output is on a single line.

Comment: Definitely forgot it, thanks, I'm updating my answer! Btw you can use the same logic with pprint, but instead of doing `of.write(msg)` you can define `pp_to_f = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, stream=of)` and then  do`pp_to_f.pprint(msg)`. Haven't tested id but it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `tee` command, for example: `pythonscript.py | tee console_output.txt`

Comment: This produces the exact same as result as `script.py > output.txt`. The output file is created, but nothing gets added to it. Again, not sure why this worked before and now it doesn't.

Comment: if you run your `pythonscript.py` without pipe or redirection, do you see anything on the screen? Can you share a snippet of your code?

Can you try `python -c "print('Hello World')" | tee console_output.txt`? Check if you see `Hello World` on the console and the file.

Comment: Interesting, that works completely fine. And yes, if I just do `python app.py` I can see the stdout in the terminal. @MatteoMoreschini has got a solution that works for me though, so there no need to investigate further. Thank you!